# Downsample weekly to daily data using SQL or Pandas

Tags: mysql, pandas

I have weekly data going back to 2009.  I am looking take this weekly data and interpolate it to daily data.  This is sales data so there is certainly day/weekend trends, so I'd like to do something smarter than just dividing the weekly number by 7.  However all the datapoints end on Saturdays so I would have to take some standard weighting scheme perhaps.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table with one row per day of week, and an associated weighting value (a percentage of the weekly total).

```
CREATE TABLE WeightByDow (
 dow TINYINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 weight DECIMAL(2,2) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO WeightByDow (dow, weight) VALUES
(1, 0.10), (2, 0.16), (3, 0.16), (4, 0.16), (5, 0.16), (6, 0.16), (7, 0.10);
```

Choose whatever you want for the weights, but make sure they add up to 1.00.

Then you can join to your weekly data:

```
SELECT d.date - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(d.date) DAY + INTERVAL w.dow DAY AS date,
  d.value * w.weight AS daily_value
FROM WeeklyData AS d
CROSS JOIN WeightByDow AS w
```

I have never used Pandas so I can't comment on how to use this technique with that framework.